# How to get a reference to list view object from code behind file in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a list view in my xamarin forms `MainPage.xaml` and a code behind file called `MainPage.xaml.cs`, I need to be able to manipulate the list view from the code behind file. I am using the 32 Feet.Net library to query for the bluetooth devices(`paired and unpaired`).
Here is the listview residing in my layout file

```
  <ListView
            x:Name="mylist"
            Margin="40"
        >
</ListView>
```

I am trying to populate the names of the discovered Bluetooth devices into that using C# and here is the button handler method in my code behind file

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        //declare the ListView in code behind file
        private ListView bNames;
        private BluetoothRadio radio;
        BluetoothClient client;
        int count = 0;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //get the default adapter
            radio= BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio;
            //enable the adapter if not enabled
            if (radio.HardwareStatus == HardwareStatus.Running)
            {
               
            }
            client = new BluetoothClient();
            //how to assign bNames?
            
            
        }

        private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get the list of bonded devices
            BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices = client.DiscoverDevices();
            //populate the devices into the list view from our layout
            //how do I grab the list view object from my layout and populate data programatically
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey guys I just discovered there is this method `FindByName(string name)`, all I need is to cast to  list view object

Comment: you have already assigned a name to your ListView, so you can just refer to it by that name in the code behind.  Typically you would bind the `ItemsSource` to an `IEnumerable` in your code-behind or VM, and then just add data to that as needed.  There are numerous examples of working with ListView this way.

Comment: The item source works the same way as `datagridview.DataSource` where you assign an array enumarable?

Comment: Yes.  This is very well documented.

Comment: It worked, the list view showed the items from the array, do you know of any other Bluetooth library I can use for this, In The Hand just proved incompatible with Monodroid v12, can I downgrade that?

Comment: How do I change the styling when an item is selected, it is highlighting the background to be orange?

Comment: there are numerous existing questions about modifying the selected item color